# Matplotlib: Same height for subfigures

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, imshow

in the following example, how can I set both subfigures to the same height?

```
#minimal example
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
im = np.random.random((100,100))
ax1.imshow(im)
ax1.set_xlim(0, im.shape[1])
ax1.set_ylim(0, im.shape[0])
x = np.arange(100)
ax2.plot(x, x**2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib.gridspec`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

# Add subplots using gridspec instead of plt.subplots()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2, height_ratios=[1,1])
f = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])

im = np.random.random((100,100))
ax1.imshow(im)
ax1.set_xlim(0, im.shape[1])
ax1.set_ylim(0, im.shape[0])
x = np.arange(100)
ax2.plot(x, x**2)
```

Produces output like:

[image: Example image for same height using gridspec]

Comment: This fails on my machine: ``ValueError: Expected the given number of height ratios to match the number of rows of the grid`` (in the ``GridSpec`` constructor)

Answer (score 0):

As [Wenzel Jakob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130282/wenzel-jakob) says, [RickardSjogren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3635816/rickardsjogren)'s answer gives the same error for me.

The correct parameter that should be given to `GridSpec` will be `width_ratios`. To make the height of the images to be the same, `width_ratios` are set as the list of aspect ratios of the images.

The following code will work properly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

im1 = np.random.normal(size=(100, 200))
im2 = np.random.normal(size=(200, 100))

aspect1 = im1.shape[1] / im1.shape[0]
aspect2 = im2.shape[1] / im2.shape[0]

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[aspect1, aspect2])

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax1.imshow(im1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax2.imshow(im2)

plt.show()
```

The output I got is the following.

[image: result]