# How to force equal subplot size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I am trying to plot 3 graphs in a single row, but all plots should be the same size (at least the same height).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

x = np.random.uniform(size=2000) - 0.5
y = np.random.uniform(size=2000) - 0.5
z = np.random.uniform(size=2000) - 0.5
DPI = 106

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(900 / DPI, 350 / DPI))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3, width_ratios=[1,1,1])

# 1D
r = np.abs(x)
# plot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
plot = ax1.scatter(x, r, s = 1, c=r, cmap='jet', marker='.', alpha = 1, vmax = 0.5)
ax1.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax1.set_ylabel('$y$')
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

# 2D
r = np.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
# plot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
plot = ax2.scatter(x, y, s = 1, c=r, cmap='jet', marker='.', alpha = 1, vmax = 0.5)
ax2.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax2.set_ylabel('$y$')
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
fig.colorbar(plot, shrink = 1, ax = ax2)


# 3D
r = np.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2], projection='3d')
plot = ax3.scatter(x, y, z, s = 10, c=r, cmap='jet', marker='.', alpha = 1, vmax = 0.5)

ax3.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax3.set_ylabel('$y$')
ax3.set_zlabel('$z$')
ax3.view_init(30, 240)
ax3.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
fig.colorbar(plot, shrink = 1,ax = ax3)

fig.tight_layout()
```

The code above does produce three columns of plots, first 1D, than 2D and lastly a 3D plot. However, as you can see from attached image, the plots are not of the same size eventhough I tried using `gridspec`as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29118050/5970596).

[image]

Any ideas on how to change the size of subplots?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib.pyplot's auto-layout algorithm does not care if you are plotting a 3D object, 2D object or 1D (points).  Of course the syntax for defining the object will change and a 3D object will take 3 parameters.  But how the objects are placed in a row is not changed.  I see a few possible reasons why **your specific data** may be causing you trouble.

The first image is 2D and has a smaller y-axis scale than the other 2 images.  Also the 1st image x-axis scale is twice as wide as y-axis scale is tall. The 2nd and 3rd images include vertical colormaps, which makes these images taller in total.

1) You can change the 1st plot's y-axis to be taller than it currently is.

```
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
```

This code in your 1st plot is preventing you from changing the y-axis scale only.  You can remove this line and manually set the scale of y-axis scale to be larger.

2) Make your entire row taller, so the vertical colormaps in 2nd and 3rd plots will not determine the overall height of the figure space.  Set the **figsize's x and y attribute to (12, 12)** and see if that fixes the issue.  The 2nd number in figsize sets height.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 12))
```

3) Alternatively, you can plot 1st graph in it's own 1st row, and 2nd and 3rd graphs in a separate 2nd row.  Set nrows to 2 and ncols to 2, then add 1st plot to row 1 and col 1, and 2nd plot to row 2, col 1, and 3rd plot to row 2, col 2.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 18))
```

You can refer to Matplotlib documentation for getting details setting layout parameters.  Hope one of these will work.  :-)

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html

[image: Matplotlib set_aspect docs]

Comment: It is very important that one of the plots is in 3D space. Why? Because your first solution looks promising but I can't get it working id one of the plots is 3D.

Comment: 3D plots should not matter.  Try increasing y-axis scale on the first plot.  Or try manually making the first plot height larger. :-)

Comment: `Projection = '3d'`has to be set for a 3D plot (or something similar).